# How to tell rebot.py where to place logs and reports?

Tags: logging, report, robotframework

I'd like to use rebot.py in a script to create and put logs and reports into a given folder. Log and report parameters just don't work:

```
milo@automoso:~/temp/demoproject> ./rebot demo_output.xml --log /home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/log.html --report /home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/report.html
[ WARN ] Arguments '--log', '/home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/log.html', '--report' and '/home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/report.html' did not exist and were ignored. Validate the used command line syntax.
Log:     /home/milo/temp/demoproject/log.html
Report:  /home/milo/temp/demoproject/report.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options have to go before the name of the output file. Move "demo_output.xml" to the end of the command. Otherwise, rebot thinks all of those arguments are the names of output files.

```
./rebot --log /home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/log.html --report /home/autotest/milo/robot_logs/report.html demo_output.xml
```

If you run the command `rebot --help` it will show this usage at the top of what it prints out:

```
Usage:  rebot|jyrebot|ipyrebot [options] robot_outputs
   or:  python|jython|ipy -m robot.rebot [options] robot_outputs
   or:  python|jython|ipy path/to/robot/rebot.py [options] robot_outputs
   or:  java -jar robotframework.jar rebot [options] robot_outputs
```

Comment: Damn, you are right. I should have read the usage more carefully. :)